# LDAP Authentication using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I am trying to use LDAP authentication using PHP.
Below is my code:

```
<?php

$ldaphost = 'ldap://ldapServer';
$ldapport = 389;

$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
//ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
if ($ds) 
{
    $username = "testuser@domain.com";
    $upasswd = "testpass";

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $upasswd);


    if ($ldapbind) 
        {print "Congratulations! $username is authenticated.";}
    else 
        {print "Access Denied!";}


}
?>
```

But it raises the below error:

> PHP Warning:  `ldap_bind()`: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Any idea as how can I get it resolved?

**Note:** Do we need `ldap.config` file somewhere as I came across this term on some forum. I don't see any such file on my machine. I have `php_ldap.dll` in ext folder and using `Windows`.

Comment: Can you use `mod_auth_ldap`? This will do everything for you.

Comment: The first argument to `ldap_connect()` does not require the `ldap://` wrapper, it automatically assumes you are connecting to an LDAP server, you only need to specify a protocol if you are using `ldaps://`. Try just supplying the hostname/IP address. Also, verify that the LDAP server is able to accept connections from external machines on TCP/UDP 389 (check the firewall and the binding address of the server). You should not need `ldap.config`. Note that `ldap_connect()` - despite the name - does *not* initiate a connection to the server, it only prepares the resource for use.

Comment: in addition to @DaveRandom's suggestion - try the basics first - are you able to resolve the hostname of the server from your machine? If not, use the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

When you bind, you bind not to the username, but to [DN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#Directory_structure).

Your $username variable should look like this:

```
$username = 'uid=testuser,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com';
```

Comment: Actually, that depends on whether you're connecting to Microsoft Active Directory or any other LDAP directory. AD can handle Username + Domain/UPN (User Principle Name), but other LDAP directories requires (?) distinguished name.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [ldap_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php) doesn't requires the protocol, so this naive patch should solve your issue:

```
--- ldap.php.bak    2012-09-04 10:52:29.563203493 +0200
+++ ldap.php    2012-09-04 10:52:46.807203766 +0200
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 <?php

-$ldaphost = 'ldap://ldapServer';
+$ldaphost = 'ldapServer';
 $ldapport = 389;

 $ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
```

Check the [basic example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-basic.php) at the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer for it not but I would like to add something from my experience.

```
$username   = 'bentcoder';
$password   = '123123';
$server = '192.168.32.4';
$domain = '@yourdomain.com';
$port       = 389;

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($server, $port);

if (! $ldap_connection)
{
    echo '<p>LDAP SERVER CONNECTION FAILED</p>';
    exit;
}

// Help talking to AD
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$ldap_bind = @ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $username.$domain, $password);

if (! $ldap_bind)
{
    echo '<p>LDAP BINDING FAILED</p>';
    exit;
}

// You can work now!!!

ldap_close($ldap_connection);
```

**Notes:**

- `php_ldap` extension should be enabled in php.ini.
  [extension=php_ldap.dll]
- IP address above [192.168.32.4] can be replaced with [yourdomain.com]
- If you're using Wamp then you might run into strange issues so as far
  as remember all worked fine under version 1.9 but not with above
  versions.

**References:**

- [Mozilla LDAP C SDK Programmer's Guide](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk-docs/filter.htm)
- [LDAP Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php)

Answer (score 0):

We proved it in a local network and it worked well. If for example you are using Ldap with Zentyal go `https://serveriporname/Users/Composite/Settings` and then take the options it gives you in the "User DN" so you take that addresss we will call `$userdns` and you may prove the following code

```
<?php
       //The variables are implicit

    $ad = ldap_connect($ldap_server) ;  //Ex: 10.0.0.1
    ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) ; 

       //Using the provided user and password to login into LDAP server.
       //For the dc, normally will be the domain. 

        $sr=ldap_search($ad, $userdns, "cn=*usuario*");

        $info = ldap_get_entries($ad, $sr);

       for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
          /*Print out the user information here. If you rather to request by other field than cn take its name from here*/
          print_r($info[$i]);
          echo "<p><hr/></p>";
        }
       $ds = ldap_bind($ad,"uid=$ldap_user,$userdns",$ldap_pass);
       if($ds){
      echo "<h4>$ldap_user connect to LDAP server \"$ldap_domain\"</h4>";
       } else {
         echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
       }  
       ldap_close($ad);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Minras was saying, you are binding with the wrong credentials. Try something like this:

```
$ldaprdn  = 'cn=binder,dc=domain,dc=com';     // ldap rdn or dn or proxy agent or admin
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("54.85.xx.xx")
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

// Set some ldap options for talking to 
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ldapconn) {

        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "Done..\n</h1>";
        } else {
            echo "Damn you LDAP...\n";
        }

}
```